# Resizing and styling the Google Cast button <google-cast-launcher>

Tags: css, chromecast, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I have a simple page where I'm loading the Cast Application Framework:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/cv/js/sender/v1/cast_sender.js?loadCastFramework=1"></script>
```

This page follows the [example for a standard cast button](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/chrome_sender/integrate):

```
<google-cast-launcher></google-cast-launcher>
```

By default, this button is huge and takes up all the space on the page.  So, I try to resize it with CSS:

```
google-cast-launcher {
  max-width: 2em;
}
```

This has no effect.  Neither does setting explicit `height` and `width`.

The documentation is not helpful:

> You can apply any additional styling, such as size or positioning, to the element as necessary.

How do I style this button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element is set to `display: inline` by default - those have neither width or height attributes available. Set it to `display: inline-block` or `display: block`.

Answer (score 2):

This works fine for me. Please see below, thanks.

```
google-cast-launcher {

 float: right;

 margin: 10px 6px 14px 0px;

 width: 40px;

 height: 32px;

 opacity: 0.7;

 background-color: #000;

 border: none;

 outline: none;

}
 
google-cast-launcher:hover {

 --disconnected-color: white;

 --connected-color: white;

}
```